# Is it possible to refer to a fields parent class

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Using: Delphi XE2

A class has a field that is another class.

Is it possible in a procedure of the field to refer to the container class?

```
Type TClassA = class
 procedure ClassAMethod;
end;

Type TClassB = class
 ClassA : TClassA; 
end;

procedure TClassA.ClassAMethod;
begin
 // is it possible to get a reference to the 
 // owning ClassB object here?
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. There is no inherent connection between those two objects. If the contained objects needs to refer to the container, then the contained class needs to be given a reference to that object. Pass it in as a constructor parameter, for example:

```
constructor TClassB.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  ClassA := TClassA.Create(Self);
end;
```

If these objects descend from `TComponent`, then you might be able to use the [`Owner`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Owner) property for this.